# Creating Mongo users in Docker on Container creation

Tags: mongodb, docker

so I am having trouble creating mongo containers, then creating a db and a user for that db. I have a batch file that does Docker Run, then it waits a period of time, then it uses `docker -u <uname> -p <pwrd> < ./setup.js`.

Then in the js file i have

```
use <dbname>
db.createUser({user: '<dbuname>', pwd: '<pwrd>', roles: [{role: 'dbOwner', db: '<dbname>'}]})
```

But it seems it comes up with and error that this user is already created. But when I go into the docker shell and into mongo, i switch to that db, and do show users, db.getUsers(); etc with nothing returned.

When i move the code out of the js file and into a -eval variable, the cli shows a user created, but i still can't see after when going into the container.

Any ideas what is going on here?